# Time complexity for the given code

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

### Question

> Find the time complexitty for the given code.

```
sum = 0
for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
    for(j=1; j<=i; j++){
        if(j%i == 0){
            for(k=1; k<=n; k++){
                sum = sum + k;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know this question is already posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472901/what-are-the-time-complexities-of-the-following-c-codes),But i want to solve it by my own so that i can get the feel of the question.

#### My approach

For $i=1,j$ will execute $1$ time,k will execute $n$times and hence sum will execute $n^2$ times

For $i=2,j$ will execute $2$ times,k will execute $n + \frac{n}{2}$times and hence sum will execute $(n + \frac{n}{2}) \times n$ times

For $i=3,j$ will execute $3$ times,k will execute $n + \frac{n}{2}+ \frac{n}{3}$times and hence sum will execute  $(n + \frac{n}{2}+\frac{n}{3}) \times n$ times

I am clueless to move forward , please help me out !

Comment: The question only asked for the complexity, so you don't need the exact number.

Comment: To be pedantic, this requires that we know the (relative) time complexity of each operation involved. Specifically, all the `++` operators, the four `if`-tests and finally, the innermost `sum = sum + k`. The answer will differ depending on whether all of these have similar time complexity, or if, say, the `sum = sum + k` has significantly larger complexity than the others.

Comment: @Arthur thanks for your point.But i am interested  in finding the time complexity of the code assuming that number of times sum will be executed will give us the required result

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your interest is in investigating the number of times the line of code `sum = sum+k`

Let $I_p$ be the indicator variable.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n I_{j|i}n=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(I_{i|i} n + \sum_{j\neq i}I_{j|i}n\right)=\sum_{i=1}^nn=n^2$$

Remark: Of course there are values of $i$ and $j$ where that line of code is not implemented. The complexity of those would be $\Theta(n^2)$ as well.